# The value of a function parameter cannot be used as a constant C++

Tags: c++, casting, c++17

```
void myFilter (int filter_length, int num_channels)
{
    IIR::Filter* f = new IIR::SmoothedFilterDesign
        < IIR::RBJ::Design::LowPass, num_channels> (filter_length);
}
```

I am getting the error that

> "expression must have a constant value. The value of parameter "num_channels" cannot be used as a constant".

The `SmoothedFilterDesign` class can take up to three inputs as shown below.

```
template <class DesignClass,
          int Channels,
          class StateType = DirectFormII>
class SmoothedFilterDesign
    : public FilterDesign <DesignClass,
                         Channels,
                         StateType>
```

What would be the most efficient to get around this problem?

Comment: `template <int num_channels> void myFilter (int filter_length)`?

Comment: The template parameters must be known in compile time, therefore it cannot be a runtime parameter. You either have to hard-code the number of channels in `myFilter` or make `myFilter` a template function that receives the number if channels as a template parameter.

Comment: How many possible values are there for the number of channels? Assuming that this is for audio, there are probably just a handful, and you can use a conditional or switch that instantiates the appropriate template for each value.